# When using Graph API for mass notification, how do I make it efficient?

Tags: .net, facebook, c#-4.0, facebook-c#-sdk

*I'm using the Facebook C# SDK and am looking for an answer in context of that library, however general info might also be helpful.*

### Question

When accessing multiple Facebook users (e.g. to send a message to all authed users of an application) is it best to use GRAPH API or a more efficient method?

### Efficiency

I can use the Graph API's [https://graph.facebook.com/*userid*](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user) call (**requires one call for each user info wanted**),  but it feels inefficient to make a Graph API call for each user.

The Old REST API had the call [users.getInfo](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/users.getinfo) from which multiple user's info could be retrieved at once, however the REST API is being deprecated and Facebook recommends not using it any longer.

My other thought is FQL might be viable to get all users at once; however if I can instead call the Graph API once per user without repercussion (e.g. # request governance, rate limiting, etc) then I prefer to stick with that.

Any other options?

### Rate Limits?

I've seen discussion on Graph API rate limits like [here](http://www.quora.com/Whats-the-Facebook-Open-Graph-API-rate-limit) and [here](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=56950) but don't know if this is really a concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to grab information about multiple users you can use https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=4,152078551499478&fields=name (ids=uid1,uid2,etc&fields=field1,field2,etc) or something similar. If this becomes big enough send it as a POST and add a method=GET argument so that FB will treat it as a GET for purposes of the graph API.

Comment: Thanks for the info. That works great. Now I will figure out how to do the same from the Facebook C# SDK. I replaced your link format example with a working version.